# Can someone explain the reasoning for this Lemma or direct me to a proof?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> **Lemma 10.1.** *Let $\sigma$ be a permutation in $Sym(\{r,s,t\})$. If $\sigma$ has order 1 or 3, then*
>
> $$\sigma(\lambda^3)=\lambda^3 \textit{ and } \sigma(\mu^3)=\mu^3.$$
>
> *If $\sigma$ has order 2, then $\sigma$ interchanges $\lambda^3$ and $\mu^3$*.
>
> In any case, it follows that every permutation in $Sym(\{r,s,t\})$ fixes both
>
> $$\lambda^3 + \mu^3\text{ and }\lambda^3\cdot\mu^3,$$
>
> i.e. these are symmetric polynomials in $r,s,t$. As a somewhat tedious exercise, you will be asked to write out $\lambda^3+\mu^3$ explicitly as a polynomial in $r,s,t,$ and then to express it as a polynomial in the three elementary symmetric functions in $r,s,t.$

This is in the cubic and quartic equations section of this book.

Comment: Need some context. For example, what are $\lambda$ and $\mu$?

Comment: What is "this book"?